# Technique to map any number of varying data schemas into a normalised repository

Tags: database, transformation, xsd-validation

I'm looking for some guidance, what's the best way to transform data from A to B.  I.e. if each client has different data but essentially recording the same details, what is the best way to transform this into a common schema?

**Simple example showing different schemas**

```
Client A | Id | Email | PricePaid | Date              |
Client B | Id | Email | Price     | DateOfTransaction |
```

**Result schema**

```
| Id | Email | Price | Order_Timestamp |
```

This simple example shows two clients record essentially the same things but with different names for the price and date of the order.  Is there a good technique to automate this for any future schema but purely through configuration?  I.e. maybe something with XML/ XSD perhaps?

Many suggestions welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Your "common schema" doesn't identify the client. That might be a *big* problem.  Is this a one-time, one-way conversion? Do you have to preserve each client's original interface for the client's use? Is this for private use, or are you building a multi-tenant database?

Comment: The common schema will allow "us" to run some machine learning over the data where the original data comes from different clients and varying schemas.  Would probably need to identify the client later within the data.  Is there a known "best practice" for this?

Comment: Store the client along with the client's rows. It sounds like you're working toward something more like a data warehouse than like a multi-tenant database. Imagine Walmart's data warehouse. They store data for each store (for each client). Walmart doesn't have to fuss with column names, though. Does that sound like what you're aiming at?

Comment: Yes, I think you might be right.  The machine learning needs large data to draw predications etc from a range of clients.

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like my original question still remains no?  How do I normalise the data efficiently?

Comment: Probably separate schemas (`create schema client_a;, etc`) for each client. Staging tables in the client schemas match the structure of client tables. Bulk load into staging tables, then simple SQL `insert into public.orders select ...` to populate the normalized tables.